# How to create method name using After and Equals in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I need your help to my problem. I can't create method name following [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) documentation. I want to query date by this method.

I want like this query :

```
    SELECT * FROM app_basic where app_end_date>='2016-11-29';
```

In following Spring documentation `After` keyword work fine. But I need `After` and `Equals` in method name convention using Spring Data jpa.

So, how can I create this method ? Please, help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your entity please

Answer (score 62):

You can use LessThan, GreaterThan, LessThanEqual, GreaterThanEqual also with dates.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is `LessThan` equivalent to `Before`?